# Mysql query is producing duplicate data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database set up with one table containing customers, and a second containing calls. When a customer calls in it is logged and saved as a text file to the calls database with the date time and the customer ID that called in.

Customer ID is a foreign key that links to ID in the calls table, one customer can have many calls.

I use the following to get the data from the database

```
        $result = mysql_query(" SELECT * FROM customer LEFT JOIN calllog ON calllog.customID = customer.ID INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.customer_ID   WHERE CallStatus= 'Open' ")or die(mysql_error());
```

A for loop then echoes out all of the results like so:

```
 for ($i = $start; $i < $end; $i++)
    {

            if ($i == $total_results) { break; }

            echo "<tr class='main'>";
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'First_Name') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Surname') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Company_Name') . '</td>';
            echo '<td> <div style="width: 200px">' .  nl2br(mysql_result($result, $i,'line_1')) . '</div></td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'town') . '</td>';
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'customer.ID') . '</td>';

            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'Telephone') . '</td>';

            echo '<td><a href="callJob.php?id=' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '"><img src="img\job.jpg" title="New Job"/></a></td>';
    echo '<td><button class= "Call" id="Calllog' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'id') . '"></></ /></a></td>';

            echo "</tr>"; 


            echo "<tr>";
             echo '<td colspan="13"><div ">' .  nl2br(mysql_result($result, $i, 'CallNotes')) . '</div></td>'; //Display notes
            echo '<td>' . mysql_result($result, $i, 'CallTime') . '</td>';
            echo "</tr>"; 

    }
    echo "</table>";
```

multiple call notes are attached to a single customer however I am getting duplicate customers when they have multiple calls. It will echo out:

```
Tom
Call log1

Jim
Call log1

Tom 
call log 2
```

I was expecting it to go

```
Tom
Call Log1
Call log2

Jim 
Call log 1.
```

Comment: Please stop using `mysql_` functions, *they are deprecated*.

Comment: As @JayBlanchard has mentioned, [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add group by clause to your SQL statement

```
SELECT * 
FROM customer 
LEFT JOIN calllog ON calllog.customID = customer.ID 
INNER JOIN address ON customer.ID = address.customer_ID
WHERE CallStatus= 'Open' 
GROUP BY customer.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your INNER JOIN is the culprit change that to an LEFT JOIN.